# Change author font for specific cite command

Tags: biblatex, formatting

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\textcite{knuth:ct:e}\\
\fullcite{salam}\\
Footcite\footfullcite{baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This will print author surnames in small caps for all cite command both in the document and in the bibliography. Just for the `\textcite` command I want the surname (i.e Knuth in the example) to be printed in the text in regular font rather than in small caps.

EDIT: As of March 2016 (biblatex 3.3), you need to change `\mkbibnamefamily` instead of `\mkbibnamelast`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is to introduce a toggle to determine whether we are in a text cite or not. Then the modification of `\mkbibnamelast` is parametrised to the toggle. This solution uses the `xpatch` package to modify the `textcite` bibmacro, to set the toggle to true just before executing the `textcite` macro and to false right after the `textcite` macro has been executed.

```
\newtoggle{textcite}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{textcite}{#1}{\textsc{#1}}}
}

\xpretobibmacro{textcite}{\toggletrue{textcite}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{textcite}{\togglefalse{textcite}}{}{}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{\textsc{#1}}}
\let\TC\textcite
\renewcommand\textcite[1]{{\def\mkbibnamelast##1{##1}\TC{#1}}}% hold it local
%% If you need the optional argument of \textcite then we have to modify
%% the macro    

\begin{document}
\textcite{knuth:ct:e}\\
\fullcite{salam}\\
Footcite\footfullcite{baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This completely breaks the syntax of `\textcite`: `\textcite[⟨prenote⟩][⟨postnote⟩]{⟨key⟩}`

Answer (score 0):

With more recent versions of `biblatex` we can use an approach similar to [Guido](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16895/guido)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203350/35864), but instead of patching citation commands to set a flag we test for the delimiter context.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{%
  \ifcsundef{mkbibnamefamily@\blx@delimcontext}
    {\textsc}
    {\csuse{mkbibnamefamily@\blx@delimcontext}}}

\newcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily@textcite}[1]{#1}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\textcite{knuth:ct:e}

\fullcite{salam}

Footcite\footfullcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Knuth (1986)" no small caps//"Abdus Salam (1968)." "Salam" in small caps]