# Multiple \finalnamedelim in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, delimiters

In biblatex, if I have (A, B and C, 2014), I can change that to (A, B & C, 2014) using

```
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{ \& }
```

Now I would like to preserve the original 'and' only in the command `\citeauthor` (instead of having "&" there as well). Is that possible?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). As Peter Gill keeps saying, solving problems can be fun but setting them up isn't! An MWE will also provide us with important information about how you are configuring your references and help to ensure that answers address your question rather than a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt the solution proposed in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203350/16895.

We create a toggle and set it to true just before executing the loop code of the cite command for `\citeauthor`, and set the toggle false after the name has been printed.

```
\newtoggle{citeauthor}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\toggletrue{citeauthor}%
    \ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \togglefalse{citeauthor}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Would you mind telling me where you found the definition of `\citeauthor`? I couldn't find it in `authoryear.cbx` in my distribution's directory.

Comment: It is in `biblatex.def`. It contains common commands, macros and hooks.