# How to change author font to smallcaps in fullcite command only?

Tags: biblatex

I have been searching for a while, and I have tried to rely on [this question and its accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203311/change-author-font-for-specific-cite-command) to modify the `\fullcite` command so the name of the author appears in small caps for this particular `cite` command but remains in normal font for the rest of the `cite` commands. Unfortunatley, I must be doing something wrong because I get the authors in smallcaps for all `cite` commands. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% PACKAGES 

\usepackage{xpatch} % To modify the fullcite command.
\usepackage{filecontents} % To get the bibliography inside the tex file

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true]{biblatex} % To get fancy bibliography as desired.
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

% REDEFINITION 

\newtoggle{fullcite}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{fullcite}{#1}{\textsc{#1}}}
}

\xpretobibmacro{fullcite}{\toggletrue{fullcite}}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{fullcite}{\togglefalse{fullcite}}{}{}

% DOCUMENT 

\begin{document}

\fullcite{author_book} [This is fine]

\citet{author_book} [This is wrong: it should remain in normal font]

\citeauthor{author_book} [This is wrong: it should remain in normal font]

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

How can I change the font of author in the `fullcite` command only? Thank you all.

**EDIT 1**: although Ivan's solution works, it fails when the preamble includes the line `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}`. I need to find a solution that is compatible with `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}`. Thank you all!

**EDIT 2**: I have opened [a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586674/how-to-change-author-font-to-smallcaps-in-fullcite-command-only-follow-up) with a better specification of what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have to redefine the \fullcite command to use another name format that we call `scname`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usedriver
 {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{scname}}%<<modified
 {\thefield{entrytype}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Then I see two possible solutions.

**First solution:**

```
\letbibmacro{scname:given-family}{name:given-family}
\xpretobibmacro{scname:given-family}
 {\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}}{}{}

\DeclareNameFormat{scname}{%
 \ifgiveninits
 {\usebibmacro{scname:given-family}%<<modified
  {\namepartfamily}
  {\namepartgiveni}
  {\namepartprefix}
  {\namepartsuffix}}
 {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
  {\namepartfamily}
  {\namepartgiven}
  {\namepartprefix}
  {\namepartsuffix}}%
 \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

**Second solution:** (You do not need `xpatch` here.)

```
\DeclareNameFormat{scname}{%
 \ifgiveninits
 {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
  {\scshape\namepartfamily}%<<modified
  {\namepartgiveni}
  {\namepartprefix}
  {\namepartsuffix}}
 {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
  {\namepartfamily}
  {\namepartgiven}
  {\namepartprefix}
  {\namepartsuffix}}%
 \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

#### MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
 @book{author_book,
  title = {Book's title},
  author = {Author, Some},
  location = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2005},
 }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true]{biblatex} % To get fancy bibliography as desired.
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usedriver
 {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{scname}}
 {\thefield{entrytype}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% FIRST SOLUTION
\letbibmacro{scname:given-family}{name:given-family}
\xpretobibmacro{scname:given-family}
{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}}{}{}

\DeclareNameFormat{scname}{%
 \ifgiveninits
 {\usebibmacro{scname:given-family}
  {\namepartfamily}
  {\namepartgiveni}
  {\namepartprefix}
  {\namepartsuffix}}
 {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
  {\namepartfamily}
  {\namepartgiven}
  {\namepartprefix}
  {\namepartsuffix}}%
 \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
    
%SECOND SOLUTION
%\DeclareNameFormat{scname}{%
% \ifgiveninits
% {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
%  {\scshape\namepartfamily}
%  {\namepartgiveni}
%  {\namepartprefix}
%  {\namepartsuffix}}
% {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
%  {\namepartfamily}
%  {\namepartgiven}
%  {\namepartprefix}
%  {\namepartsuffix}}%
% \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{document}
 
 \fullcite{author_book} [This is fine]
 
 \citet{author_book} [This is wrong: it should remain in normal font]
 
 \citeauthor{author_book} [This is wrong: it should remain in normal font]
 
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: OK... Two questions here: (i) *which of the two solutions would you favour and why?*; & (ii) *why does your solution work fine with `article` documentclass but fails with `beamer` documentclass?* Although I failed to mention it in the OP, I'm looking for a solution that works for both `article` & `beamer` documentclasses...

Comment: 1) The first solution is conceptually more correct; 2) For me it works even if I simply replace `article` with `beamer`...

Comment: **Thank you for your answer**. After playing around for a little while, I have been able to identify which piece of code in my Beamer presentation makes your solutions fail. It's this piece: `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}`. How would you modify your solutions to make them work with this piece of code I'm using?

Comment: Please open another question

Comment: I thought that the best way to approach this sort of issues was by relying on the comments rather than by opening new questions. Regardless, I have followed your andvice and opened a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586674/how-to-change-author-font-to-smallcaps-in-fullcite-command-only-follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

With name wrapper formats you can avoid having to redefine or patching name formats. You can just inject the redefinition for small caps before the name is printed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
  maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=3,
  isbn=false,
  natbib,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{smallcaps}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}%
  #1}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{smallcaps}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{sigfridsson}

\citet{sigfridsson}

\citeauthor{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: "E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde" in small caps]

In the MWE the three lines

```
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}%
```

are superfluous, but they may be needed for different styles, so I thought it might be a nice idea to keep them (check with `style=numeric,` to see a case where the lines are required).