# How to change author font to smallcaps in fullcite command only? [Follow-up]

Tags: biblatex

I recently posted [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/586627/edit) asking how to modify the `\fullcite` command so the name of the author appears in small caps for this particular `cite` command but remains in normal font for the rest of the `cite` commands. Although I got an answer with two options that work, I need a different answer because the inclusion of `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}` in the preamble of my Beamer presentation makes those approaches fail. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% PACKAGES 

\usepackage{filecontents} % To get the bibliography inside the tex file

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[isbn=false,giveninits=true,uniquename=init,style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=3,hyperref=true]{biblatex} % To get fancy bibliography as desired.
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

% DOCUMENT 

\begin{document}

\fullcite{author_book} [The author here should appear in small caps.]

\citet{author_book} [The author here should appear in normal font.]

\citeauthor{author_book} [The author here should appear in small caps.]

\end{document}
```

How can I change the font of author in the `fullcite` command only while using `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}`? Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

\DeclareNameFormat{family-given}{%
 \ifgiveninits
 {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
  {\scshape\namepartfamily}
  {\namepartgiveni}
  {\namepartprefix}
  {\namepartsuffix}}
 {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
  {\namepartfamily}
  {\namepartgiven}
  {\namepartprefix}
  {\namepartsuffix}}%
 \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

Comment: **Thank you**. It is indeed enough. And elegant!

Answer (score 2):

[My answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586717/35864) to [your earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586627/35864) also works perfectly fine without change if you include `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
  maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=3,
  isbn=false,
  natbib,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{smallcaps}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}%
  #1}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{smallcaps}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{sigfridsson}

\citet{sigfridsson}

\citeauthor{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: "Sigfridsson, E. and Ryde, U." in small caps]

Though I would be inclined to replace `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}` with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` here and tell `\fullcite` not to alias `sortname` to `default`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
  maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames=3,
  isbn=false,
  natbib,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{smallcaps}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}%
  #1}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}%
      \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{smallcaps}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{sigfridsson}

\citet{sigfridsson}

\citeauthor{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.